# How to pass arguments to a controller init method?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

How can I pass external values into a controller. In the below code I would like to pass in values `filtertype` and `filterterm` from `PostsController` into `PostsDynamicController`. What is a way do achieve this?

I have a template like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">             
                    {{view Ember.Select
                    contentBinding="App.names.content"
                    valueBinding="App.names.selected"
                    }}
                    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="filterterm" }}
                     <button {{action "submit"}} > Submit</button>
        {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

Part of my App.js is this:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   content: [],
   filterterm: "",
   submit: function () {
       var filtertype =  App.names.selected;
       var filterterm =  this.get('filterterm');
       this.transitionToRoute("posts.dynamicfinder");
   }
});

App.PostsDynamicController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function () {
    //want access to filtertype and filterterm here so that I can pass them in find. i.e.
    //App.Request.find(filtertype: filterterm);
    this.set('model', App.Request.find(..);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass args to the controller's init() function.

To pass external values into a controller you should use bindings. Specifically the controller's `needs` property. See the ember guide [dependencies-between-controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

So for example:

```
// Change handlebars template to valueBinding="filtertype" instead of valueBinding="App.names.selected"

// Also these should be ArrayControllers not ObjectControllers

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  filterterm: null,
  filtertype: null,
  submit: function () {
     this.transitionToRoute("posts.dynamicfinder");
  }
});

App.PostsDynamicController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['posts'],
  termBinding: 'controllers.posts.filterterm',
  typeBinding: 'controllers.posts.filtertype',
  filteredPosts: function() {
    var filtertype = this.get('type');
    var filterterm = this.get('term');
    // ...
  }.property('term', 'type')
}
```

});

Comment: If `term` and `type` are set at the end of that then how would I set the model? In this case I would want to set the model to : `.set('model', App.Request.find(type: term))`

Comment: I have a working example on jsbin if it helps: http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/33/edit When a drop down is changed and a text box value is entered and submit is clicked I would like to make a request to dynamicfinder with model `find(term: type)`

Comment: I don't think `App.Request.find(type: term)` works the way you think it does. It returns a live collection that includes every `App.Request` in the store. Then (async) it kicks off an API request with the specified query. Any objects returned by the API are added to the store and thus appear in the live collection. Sounds like what you want to return instead is a filtered collection, so that only records matching the specified term are displayed.

Comment: By default I am not displaying everything to the user. So I do want to do a query against the App.Request so that it goes back to the server to fetch more requests

Comment: Makes sense. So in your submit fx just do something like `App.Response.find({filter: type, term: term});`